# How does iOS compute a scrollbar's thumb's position and extent?

Tags: android, ios, scrollbar

Recently I compared the behavior of the thumb in a scrollbar between Android and iOS. I found the following:

1. There are two types to compute the thumb's offset and extent in Android (controlled by [android:smoothScrollbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3asmoothScrollbar) attribute or [setSmoothScrollbarEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSmoothScrollbarEnabled%28boolean%29) method).
2. If `smoothScrollbar` is **`false`**, the thumb looks discontinuous when scrolling.
3. If `smoothScrollbar` is **`true`**, the thumb looks smooth, but it's extent varies when scrolling if the items' height are different.
4. However, the thumb in iOS is much better. It looks quite smooth, and the extent does not change.

In Android, the method to compute the offset and extent could be found in [`AbsListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html). However, I do not know how those values are compited in iOS. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

For content offset, use `self.scrollView.contentOffset`.
For frame values (including width), use `self.scrollView.frame.size.(<>); [width, height]`, `self.scrollview.bounds;` or `self.scrollview.frame.origin.(<>); [x,y]`.

If you want to be notified of scroll events, become the scrollview's delegate.

**EDIT**

Here are the delegate methods:

Responding to Scrolling and Dragging

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

Managing Zooming

```
– viewForZoomingInScrollView:
– scrollViewWillBeginZooming:withView:
– scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:
– scrollViewDidZoom:
```

Responding to Scrolling Animations

```
– scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you know the implementation of these methods you mentioned? Thanks.